# Captcha validation always return true

Tags: php

This is my school assignment, no matter true or false the captcha input, it always returns true and head the user to home page. i don't get what part did i do wrong that caused this error

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'koneksi.php';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass= $_POST['pass'];
$captcha = $_POST['nilaicaptcha'];
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select username,password from acc where username='$username' and password='$pass'");
    if(isset($_POST['sigin'])){
        if (!isset($username) or !isset($pass)){
        echo "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        else if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0 and $captcha==$_SESSION['captcha']){
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
            header("location:home.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Salah";
            echo "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
        exit;
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['register'])){
            header("location:register.php");
    }
?>
```

i already checked that the variables are correct, there's no mistype or wrongly passed variable. i think it has to do with the `$captcha==$_SESSION['captcha']` part but im not sure why it's wrong because it seems fine to me while maybe it's not

Comment: Did you check the values if they are really what you are expecting them to be? And just to be sure, can you also add the form?

Comment: print `$captcha` and `$_SESSION['captcha']` and check both values

Comment: Captcha nya pake metode apa? Captcha dari Google atau perhitungan??

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: thanks for the help guys, silly me, i found out that the problem is with the operator. it should be ```else if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0 and $_SESSION['Captcha']===$captcha)```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help guys, i found out that the problem is with the operator. it should be `else if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0 and $_SESSION['Captcha']===$captcha)`

Answer (score -1):

Captcha validation always return true

```
if(strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha'], $_POST['captcha']) == 0)
```

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcasecmp.asp)

Comment: Please explain that further - through dumping a single line of code without any explanation, nobody can learn anything

Comment: you can  refer in link https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strcasecmp.asp

Comment: Please don't add links as an explanation - the given page doesn't even contain the word "captcha" which looks pretty important for me, regarding the title of this question

Comment: you can validate captcha value & session captcha value to find identical or not.strcasecmp is binary-safe and case-insensitive it return accurate identical result.but you can use (==) operater is find equal or not.it can not find identical or not,so using strcasecmp or (===) identical operater